# Remover "x" do Input type time

Tags: css3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para remover esse xis e essa barra de rolagem do input time?
Quero que o campo fique limpo, somente com a hora.
Lembrando que esse "xis e essa barra de rolagem" ja são padrões do input time

Comment: O "x" já é padrão do input

Comment: Creio não poder remover, quem renderiza isso é o navegador e cada navegador tem este tipo de input com a aparência específica como pode ler aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/time#Apar%C3%AAncia

Comment: @LeAndrade é verdade, mas encontrei uma solução para remover pelo menos a barra de rolagem

Comment: @hugocsl vlw me ajudou

Comment: Legal Caio que bom que ajudou ai, considere marcar a sugestão da duplicada. []´s

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí remover a barra de rolagem e o "x" que aparece no chrome com esses codigos

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button 
{
    display: none;
}

input[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="time">
```